# ios AsyncSocket peer-to-peer

Tags: ios5

Is it possible to create peer-to-peer (AsyncSocket) voice/video chat using the iphone camera without having a server?, and if possible can someone please direct the starting point.

Comment: Found a solution? Interested in his too...

Comment: I found this project called open peer.[link]http://openpeer.org